# Trying to subtract setup from cost in a NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I am trying to subtract `setup` from `cost`. So, I need to get the value from the `NumericUpDown` box and store it to an integer, which I can then use to subtract `setup` from.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int setup = 100;
    int finalcost;
    int cost;
    int priority;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        priority = trackBar1.Value;
        int cost = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {

            finalcost = cost - setup;
            MessageBox.Show(finalcost.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: And your quesiton is????

Comment: it isnt working, it doesnt set the contents of the NumericUpDown to the variable

Comment: I'm confused - which line are you saying is not working? Because I don't see any code that should be 'setting the contents' of any NumericUpDown.

Comment: I copy pasted your code to a brand new solution and it works. This line: `int cost = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;` correctly assigns value to the `cost` variable. Did you try to debug your code? Put a breakpoint in the Click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `NumericUpDown` `Maximum` property to higher than 100.